# How to select another DB in Django's ORM when used in a desktop application?

Tags: django, orm

I'm writing a desktop application with PyQt where we planned to use sqlite3-databases for file storage (instead of pickles, XML, YAML, etc). The reason is that our application is likely to migrate to a centralized data store later. (which then needs to communicate with other web based services, etc etc.)

Before everyone says "use SQLAlchemy and Elixir", I'd like to point out why chose Django, namely because:

- I know Django pretty well, it's neat and I like it's ORM.
- When we migrate, it's easy to add a web-ui on top of it.
- Having the Admin-interface makes it easy to debug/inspect the DB during development.

Anyway, my problem is that **I can't select different sqlite3 databases**, since Django's `settings.configure` throws an 'already configured' error on the second call.

Any ideas, apart from restarting the app?

*(None of many Django-desktop-orm questions here on SO seem to address this...)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paraphrasing http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Define multiple DBs in the settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'defaultdb',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
    },
    'other': {
        'NAME': 'otherdb',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}
```

Then you can choose the database manually.

```
>>> # This will run on the 'default' database.
>>> Author.objects.all()

>>> # So will this.
>>> Author.objects.using('default').all()

>>> # This will run on the 'other' database.
>>> Author.objects.using('other').all()
```

Comment: But I don't know all file files the user's will choose from the beginning. Unless I amend stuff to the DATABASES column as we go along. Slightly silly, but it could perhaps work?

Comment: Update to the above comment. I've tried it. Does not work. :-|

Comment: Marcus, what version of Django do you have, multi-db was added in version 1.2

Comment: Sorry, should've been clearer. Configuring multi-db works, but I cannot update the DATABASES dictionary after app startup, and I need to do that if the user should be able to select between different sqlite-files on the fly. (It feels a bit stupid to force an app restart.. but maybe that is a way forward.)